# Search checkboxlist item with jQuery by TEXT

Tags: jquery, asp.net, search, checkbox, checkboxlist

I need to Search checkboxlist item with jQuery by **TEXT** of the Checkbox, not by Value.

Below code search by Value

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#maincontent_txtSearchTo").on("keyup", function () {
        debugger;
        var g = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#maincontent_chkQuestionTo tr td input").each(function () {
            var s = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            $(this).parent().parent()[s.indexOf(g) !== -1 ? 'show' : 'hide']();
        });
    });
});
```

I need it to search by **TEXT**.

Please see below a sample of the generated code

```
    <input name="ctl00$maincontent$txtSearchTo" type="text" id="maincontent_txtSearchTo" Placeholder="Search..." />
    <table id="maincontent_chkQuestionTo">
    <tr>
        <td><input id="maincontent_chkQuestionTo_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$maincontent$chkQuestionTo$0" value="2057" />
<label for="maincontent_chkQuestionTo_0">What is money in finance?</label>
</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input id="maincontent_chkQuestionTo_1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$maincontent$chkQuestionTo$1" value="2058" />
<label for="maincontent_chkQuestionTo_1">What is Good?</label>
</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Grateful if you could help.

Many thanks

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume by Text, you mean label. If so, you need to use .html() on the label.

Try the code below;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#maincontent_txtSearch").on("keyup", function () {
        debugger;
        var g = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#maincontent_chkQuestion tr td input").each(function () {
            var td = $(this).parent();
            var label = $(td).find("label");

            if($(label).html().toLowerCase().indexOf(g) == -1){
               $(td).parent().hide();
            }else{
               $(td).parent().show();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Dear Jerdine, Indeed it is the text in the Label. The code is working but when searching, it does not search the first character. Could you please amend. e.g when searching **What** i dont get any result, but when I type **hat** i got the answer

Comment: @Tairon I edited the code and added .toLowerCase() on .html(), please use updated script.

Comment: Thanks so much Jerdine. 1 more advice would be welcome. I am looking for a good place / tutorial to learn JQuery. Could you please advice me. Thanks

Comment: @Tairon I'm not very familiar with those. What I do is I search what I need. For example I want to learn how to get all values from form, I search "jquery get all form values", or "jquery json form values" then most popular Stackoverflow answers show up.